# Jira reports to database

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have a jira portal for my company. I am able to get reports by downloading excel as well as on emails. I need periodic reports(once in a day) on my cloud server or to be uploaded to my database.Is there a way to do it? Are any Jira plugins available?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Jira Server installation you can use the [EazyBI App](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211051/eazybi-reports-and-charts-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) for Jira to generate this kind of reports. It also populates the data to an internal database which grants some "big data" opportunities. For Jira Cloud EazyBI is also available: [eazyBI Reports and Charts for Jira Cloud](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211508/eazybi-reports-and-charts-for-jira-cloud?hosting=cloud&tab=overview)

If you want to stay on Excel based reports, you can have a look at [Better Excel Exporter for Jira (XLSX)](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212652/better-excel-exporter-for-jira-xlsx?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview)